# Timestamp hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, timestamp

I try to return all the patients related to a particular user everything works but when I try to return the date i receive the error that I have no appropriate constructor.
this is the patient class:

```
    package com.objects;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.envers.reader.FirstLevelCache;

import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "paitentFirstName"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "paitentLastName") })

public class Patient implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    private String paitentFirstName;
    private String paitentLastName;
    private Timestamp dateOfbirth;
    private String sex;



    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name="User_Patient", 
                    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id")}, 
                    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userName")})
        private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();



     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.patient", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
      private Set<JoinDrugPatient> JoinDrugPatient = new HashSet<JoinDrugPatient>(0);


     public Patient(int id, String paitentFirstName, String paitentLastName,
             Timestamp dateOfbirth,String sex) {
        this.id = id;
        this.paitentFirstName = paitentFirstName;
        this.paitentLastName = paitentLastName;
        this.dateOfbirth = dateOfbirth;
        this.sex = sex;
    }


     public Patient(int id, String paitentFirstName,String lastName,String sex){
         this.id = id;
         this.paitentFirstName = paitentFirstName;
         this.paitentLastName=lastName;
         this.sex=sex;
     }
     public Patient(String date){
         paitentFirstName=date;
     }

     public Patient(){}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name = "paitentFirstName", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getPaitentFirstName() {
        return paitentFirstName;
    }


    public void setPaitentFirstName(String paitentFirstName) {
        this.paitentFirstName = paitentFirstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "paitentLastName", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getPaitentLastName() {
        return paitentLastName;
    }


    public void setPaitentLastName(String paitentLastName) {
        this.paitentLastName = paitentLastName;
    }


    public Timestamp getDateOfbirth() {
        return dateOfbirth;
    }


    public void setDateOfbirth(Timestamp dateOfbirth) {
        this.dateOfbirth = dateOfbirth;
    }


    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }


    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }


    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }


    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.patient", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<JoinDrugPatient> getJoinDrugPatient() {
        return JoinDrugPatient;
    }


    public void setJoinDrugPatient(Set<JoinDrugPatient> joinDrugPatient) {
        JoinDrugPatient = joinDrugPatient;
    }










    public Set<JoinDrugPatient> getStockCategories() {
        return JoinDrugPatient;
    }


    public void setStockCategories(Set<JoinDrugPatient> stockCategories) {
        this.JoinDrugPatient = stockCategories;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Patient [id=" + id + ", paitentFirstName=" + paitentFirstName
                + ", paitentLastName=" + paitentLastName + ", dateOfbirth="
                + dateOfbirth + ", sex=" + sex + "]";
    }





}
```

this is the query(hibernate)

```
List<Patient> l=session.createQuery("Select new Patient(p.id,p.paitentFirstName,p.paitentLastName,p.dateOfbirth,p.sex)"
                                        +" from Patient p join p.users a where a.UserName=?")
                                        .setParameter(0, userName)
                                        .list();
```

Comment: Why are you using new operator inside HQL and not using simply `from Patient p...`? new() operator is useful when you are building an entity constructed by other entities...  (check [select clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select))

Comment: Please auto-format your code and remove extra blank lines when posting; it makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

> This issue is not a **Hibernate** issue it is truly a **Java** issue
>   as is stated in *Effective Java (2nd Edition)*.
>
> *There are some classes in the Java platform libraries that do extend an instantiable class and add a value component. For example,
>   java.sql.Timestamp extends java.util.Date and adds a nanoseconds
>   field. The equals implementation for Timestamp does violate symmetry
>   and can cause erratic behavior if Timestamp and Date objects are used
>   in the same collection or are otherwise intermixed. The Timestamp
>   class has a disclaimer cautioning programmers against mixing dates and
>   timestamps. While you won’t get into trouble as long as you keep them
>   separate, there’s nothing to prevent you from mixing them, and the
>   resulting errors can be hard to debug. This behavior of the Timestamp
>   class was a mistake and should not be emulated. (Bloch, Effective
>   Java, 2nd Ed.)*
>
> What do you have in the class `Users`? You won't have any problem
>   if you are using `java.sql.Timestamp` everywhere in your code.